# Magento 2: how to Get Customer Recently viewed product collection

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, recently-viewed

How to get customer recently viewed product collection, I am using below code but not working anyone has an idea for same...
Bellow code always return Null or blank array

```
protected $recently_viewed;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed $recently_viewed,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->recently_viewed=$recently_viewed;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

public function getRecentProductCollection() {
        $collection=$this->recently_viewed->getItemsCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Have u found a solution yet ?

Comment: No, i left with this task , i tired a lots but not get anything